# How do i add view more/view less button in a textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I am creating an android application and i need to create a textview with view more/view less button if the number of lines cross 4 or 5 .what i need to do to implement this in my textview

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this before, but something like this should work:
Make your class implement the TextWatcher interface.

When you create your TextView, add `textView.addTextChangedListener(this);`

Then add:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(textView.getLineCount() >= 4) {
        ToggleButton showMoreToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.showMoreToggle);
        showMoreToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count) {}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
```

Then make a ToggleButton in XML and add `android:click="onClick"` and `android:visibility="gone"`. Then in your Activity code put:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) v;
    textView.setMaxLines(tb.isChecked() ? 10 : 4);
}
```

Comment: thanks geokavel for the input  , the setLines is just setting the number lines to be displayed in the textview , it is discarding the rest of the lines in the textview

Comment: Ok I added a lot more stuff now, let me know how it goes.